# Usage of infinitive instead of imperative

Tags: impératif

I'm currently spending an exchange year in France and I've stumbled upon this rather frequently. 
Here's an arbitrary example from my maths book:
"Démontrer que le volume du petit cube en cm^3 est:
                bla bla bla."
Why the infinitive form "Démontrer" instead of the imperative "Démontrez"?